# A question about a statement in the proof of Riemann Mapping Theorem from Gamelin

Tags: complex-analysis

I am reading the proof of the Riemann Mapping theorem from Gamelin's Complex Analysis,
in his proof, let $D$ be a simply connected domain where $D \neq \mathbb{C}$, ($D$ can be unbounded), fix a point $z_0 \in D$,

Gamelin defined $\mathcal{F}$ to be the collection of all univalent function defined on $D$, such that $|f(z)| < 1$ and $f(z_0) = 0$, and Gamelin claims that this collection is nonempty.

I have no idea why this is true, Gamelin's argument makes no sense to me.
His original proof is, $\mathcal{F}$ is nonempty, since if $h(z)$ maps $D$ conformally onto a bounded domain, then the function $f(z) = \epsilon(h(z) -h(z_0))$ is in $\mathcal{F}$. But he did not define what is $h(z)$.

Can somebody fill in the gap for me please?

Comment: A very clear proof of the fact that this class is non-empty is available in Rudin's RCA. See the first part of the proof of Riemann Mapping Theorem in this book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The existence of a univalent holomorphic function from $D$ onto a bounded domain is indeed an essential and non-trivial part in the proof of the Riemann mapping theorem. It is also the part where the condition that $D$ is simply connected plays a crucial role.

The proof can be found in Alhfors' “Complex Analysis“ or Rudin's “Real and Complex Analysis” books, and also in the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem#Riemann_mapping_theorem).

The argument goes roughly as follows:

- Choose $w_0 \in \Bbb C \setminus D$. Then $z-w_0$ is non-zero on the simply connected domain $D$, so that is has a holomorphic square root, i.e. a function $\phi: D \to \Bbb C$ with $\phi(z)^2 = z-w_0$.
- If $w_1 \in \phi(D)$ and $w_2 \in \phi(D)$ then $w_1 \ne -w_2$.
- Choose a disk $\overline{B_r(a)} \subset \phi(D)$ with $r < |a|$. Then $\overline{B_r(-a)} \cap D = \emptyset$.
- $h(z) = r/(\phi(z)+a)$ is holomorphic and injective in $D$ with $|h(z)| < 1$.

Comment: In the last step, we know $\phi(z)$ is injective, and injectivity is preserved under translation and dilation, but I don't remember how to show that injectivity is preserved under inversion, is there a quick argument for this?

Comment: @Andy: $h(z_1) = h(z_2) \implies \phi(z_1)+a = \phi(z_2) + a \implies \phi(z_1) = \phi(z_2) \implies z_1 = z_2$